# Why does this jquery validate rule not work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have created a jquery validate rule for following select-box and it is not working. Here is what I have done;

```
<select id="qual">
  <option value="">Choose...</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

My rule is as follows -

```
  $.validator.addMethod("qual", function(value, element, arg){

    return arg != value;
   }, "Please select a qualification.");

 $("#profile-form").validate({
    rules: {
     eduQualification:{
        qual: ""
      },
   }
)};
```

The problem is that it does not flash error message even when I select "Choose ..." from select box.

And while submitting the form; it gets submitted even if the jquery validate returned some error or not. I have called the preventDefault(); however, it seems to fail as well..

```
$(document).on('click', 'form button[type=submit]', function(e) {
            var isValid = $(e.target).parents('profile-form').isValid();

            if(!isValid) {
              e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default action
            } else{

            }
        });
```

Comment: Please don't edit the OP such that the answers become meaningless.  Thanks.

Comment: I wont. Dont worry about it.

Comment: You do NOT need a `click` handler, a `preventDefault()` or any other such thing... this plugin automatically takes care of all of this.  If your form is bypassing the validation plugin, you have a problem with your code.

Comment: Should I remove that code?

Comment: YES... it's probably making things worse.  As you can see by my demo, the code should be working:  http://jsfiddle.net/773Lozwz/

Comment: @Sparky What if I have a <form action="file.php"> ?? In that case I will need it; isn't it?

Comment: Having an `action` attribute is the default and has absolutely no bearing on this.  The plugin will always block the submit (with an internal `preventDefault` and click handler) until the form is valid.  Carefully review my jsFiddle and answer and inspect where your code is different.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/nnLs0thq/

Comment: @Sparky The form works as expected now. Thanks for the help man. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What is the `qual` rule supposed to accomplish?  Typically, a `select` only needs the `required` rule since the user can only make a selection, and has no control over the format of the selected value.
2. Your `rules` object is targeting the `eduQualification` element, but you have no element with this `name`.
3. Your closing braces for `.validate()` are backwards.  Should be `});` ... as in `.validate({...});`

Your `select` **must** contain a `name` attribute or the plugin will not work at all; and it must be `name="eduQualification"` for the way you've declared it within the `rules` object.

```
$("#profile-form").validate({
    rules: {
        eduQualification: { // <- this is the NAME
            qual: ""        // <- this is the METHOD
            ....
```

HTML:  `<select name="eduQualification" id="qual">.....`

---

To simply change the message, use the `messages` object as follows...

```
<select name="foo">
    <option value="">Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myform").validate({
        rules: {
            foo: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            foo: {
                required: "Please select a qualification."
            }

        }
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/773Lozwz/**

Comment: The rule is supposed to show the message.. "Please select your qualification". I sorted it out by setting my   <option value="-1">Choose...</option> and later checking for (value = -1). Do you have any better suggestion?

Comment: @Nevermore, you would not write a custom method to simply show a custom message.  Just change the message for the `required` rule.

Comment: I have two separate rules .. here is what you say..:

qual:{
        required: true,
      },

and its I also have its corresponding message. However, it doesnt work.

Comment: Hold on.. lemme check. Seems like a blunder in my code.

Comment: this is some kinda sorcery man.. few moments ago it was not working and now same validate rule is working.. :-D

Comment: Updated my question a bit.. Please check it